# How to prevent duplicate request by nodejs?

Tags: node.js, request

I have a distribution server that is tasked to send a request to another computer/server. I use [request](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) module for node:

```
var request     = require('request');
var destination = "http://anotherserver.com/api"
var params      = {};
request.post(destination, {form: params}, function(err, response, body) {
   // do processing here
}
```

If server don't get its answer in time (because of bad connection), `request.post` try to re-send request.

I want to prevent this. I know I can put a restriction on the receiving side, but I still want to prevent it from the source/server.

I read the manual and there's `timeout` and `time` parameter but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [manual](https://github.com/request/request#timeouts) is pretty clear about this

in your case,

```
var request     = require('request');
var destination = "http://anotherserver.com/api"
var params      = {};
request.post(destination, {form: params, timeout: 1500}, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT');
    // Set to `true` if the timeout was a connection timeout, `false` or
    // `undefined` otherwise.
    console.log(err.connect === true);
    process.exit(0);
}
```